# How to convert Android AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT into uLaw or Linear in C#

Tags: c#, android, udp, audio-streaming, multicast

I have developed two UDP multicast apps using .NET and Android. Both applications have Sender and Receiver. They are working well when I am using the same app on different devices/pc. But when I try to receive the stream from .NET App to Android or Android to .NET then getting noise voice. I have checked both apps' streaming metadata (byte) and their format is different. **Android Audio Format** is: `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT` **for Encoding** and **C# Receiver convert the coming bytes** `uLaw To Linear`.  I understand due to different algorithm implementation in both app, they are not taking the stream. Please check my code snippets for C# & Android.

**C# Codes**

```
    public static Byte[] MuLawToLinear(Byte[] bytes, int bitsPerSample, int channels)
    {
        //Anzahl Spuren
        int blockAlign = channels * bitsPerSample / 8;

        //Für jeden Wert
        Byte[] result = new Byte[bytes.Length * blockAlign];
        for (int i = 0, counter = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++, counter += blockAlign)
        {
            //In Bytes umwandeln
            int value = MulawToLinear(bytes[i]);
            Byte[] values = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);

            switch (bitsPerSample)
            {
                case 8:
                    switch (channels)
                    {
                        //8 Bit 1 Channel
                        case 1:
                            result[counter] = values[0];
                            break;

                        //8 Bit 2 Channel
                        case 2:
                            result[counter] = values[0];
                            result[counter + 1] = values[0];
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case 16:
                    switch (channels)
                    {
                        //16 Bit 1 Channel
                        case 1:
                            result[counter] = values[0];
                            result[counter + 1] = values[1];
                            break;

                        //16 Bit 2 Channels
                        case 2:
                            result[counter] = values[0];
                            result[counter + 1] = values[1];
                            result[counter + 2] = values[0];
                            result[counter + 3] = values[1];
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

**Android Codes**

```
// Audio Configuration.
int sampleRate = 16000; // How much will be ideal?
int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
boolean status = true;

String ip = getIntent().getStringExtra("ip");
final InetAddress destination = InetAddress
        .getByName(ip);
recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
        sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat, minBufSize);
recorder.startRecording();
while (status) {
    if (!startStreamThread) {
        socket.disconnect();
        socket.leaveGroup(destination);
        break;
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[2 + buffer.length];
    bytes[0] = 1;
    bytes[1] = 2;
    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, bytes, 2, buffer.length);

    String deviceIp = getIpAddress();
    minBufSize = recorder.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

    // putting buffer in the packet
    packet = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length,
            destination, DEFAULT_PORT);
    Log.e("NewOutgoing", "" + packet.getData());
    Log.e("NewDEstination; ", "" + destination);

    // packet.setData(deviceIp.getBytes());
    socket.send(packet);
}
```